# Python Multiplication Table

Tags: python

I am having trouble getting my multiplication table to look the way I was instructed to make it look.

> 0x0=0 1x0=0.....................................................9x0=0
>
> 1x1=1 2x1=1............................................9x1=9
>
> 2x2=4 3x2=6.......................................9x2=18
>
> .
>
> .
>
> .
>
> .
>
> .
>
> .
>
> .
>
> 9x9=81

So far I have this

```
   for col in range(0,1):
    for row in range(0,10):
        print(row**2, end="\n")
    print()
```

I have been fooling around with other ways to do this but its becoming a hassle for my beginner skills.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my solution. I used `string.format()` to format the string like that `0x0=0`. The parameter `end= " "` will add a space  at the end of the string.

```
for i in range(10):
    for j in range(i, 10):
        print("{}x{}={}".format(j, i, i*j), end=" ")
    print()
```

Output:

```
0x0=0 1x0=0 2x0=0 3x0=0 4x0=0 5x0=0 6x0=0 7x0=0 8x0=0 9x0=0 
1x1=1 2x1=2 3x1=3 4x1=4 5x1=5 6x1=6 7x1=7 8x1=8 9x1=9 
2x2=4 3x2=6 4x2=8 5x2=10 6x2=12 7x2=14 8x2=16 9x2=18 
3x3=9 4x3=12 5x3=15 6x3=18 7x3=21 8x3=24 9x3=27 
4x4=16 5x4=20 6x4=24 7x4=28 8x4=32 9x4=36 
5x5=25 6x5=30 7x5=35 8x5=40 9x5=45 
6x6=36 7x6=42 8x6=48 9x6=54 
7x7=49 8x7=56 9x7=63 
8x8=64 9x8=72 
9x9=81
```